# I want create new list in for loop

Tags: python

```
week_days=['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']
Week_Days=[]

for cap in week_days:
    Week_Days.append(cap.capitalize())
print(Week_Days)

print(Week_Days[:5])
print(Week_Days[5:])
```

i made days capitalization loop

but i want split to weekends and weekdays and make new list in for loop

i tried like this

```
if Week_Days <= week_days[:5]
week_days.append(Week_Days)
```

i tried several methods but made like this

```
[['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'], ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'], ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'], ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'], ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']]
```

Please teach me some hint or answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can format code blocks using three backticks (`) or tildes (~) on the lines before and after your code (_not apostrophes (') like you had earlier_). More formatting help [here](/help/formatting)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you! I'll find out more about how to use this site.

Answer (score 0):

```
week_days=['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']
Week_Days=[]
week_days1=[]
week_days2=[]

for cap in week_days:
    Week_Days.append(cap.capitalize())
    if cap in week_days[:5]:
        week_days1.append(cap.capitalize())
    else:
        week_days2.append(cap.capitalize())
        
print(Week_Days)
print(week_days1)
print(week_days2)
```

I found a solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
week_days = ['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun']
Week_Days = [day.capitalize() for day in week_days]
week_days1 = Week_Days[:5]
week_days2 = Week_Days[5:]
```

this solves the problem in the shortest amount of lines.